# How can I loop through path elements in SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg

I am getting `TypeError: logo[i].getTotalLength is not a function` error while trying to mesure the length of each `<path>` of the `<svg>` tag!

I got that error using **jquery** :

```
jQuery('#logo').each(function(i) {
        console.log( i + ' ====' + jQuery(this).get(0).getTotalLength());
   });
```

So I rewrote the same code in javascript but I still get the same error!

**javascript** code :

```
const logo= document.querySelectorAll("#logo");
for (let i=0; i < logo.length; i++)
{
    console.log(i," ==== ",logo[i].getTotalLength());
}
```

Note: in this html code there is only 1 `<path>` , I removed the others because they are very large!

html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: black;">

        <svg id="logo" width="80" height="90" viewBox="0 0 80 90" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M32.56 3.24001C41.36 3.24001 49.08 4.96001 55.72 8.40001C62.44 11.84 67.6 16.76 71.2 23.16C74.88 29.48 76.72 36.84 76.72 45.24C76.72 53.64 74.88 61 71.2 67.32C67.6 73.56 62.44 78.4 55.72 81.84C49.08 85.28 41.36 87 32.56 87H3.28V3.24001H32.56ZM31.96 72.72C40.76 72.72 47.56 70.32 52.36 65.52C57.16 60.72 59.56 53.96 59.56 45.24C59.56 36.52 57.16 29.72 52.36 24.84C47.56 19.88 40.76 17.4 31.96 17.4H20.08V72.72H31.96Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="6"/>
        </svg>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When i removed `id="logo"` from the `<svg>` tag and add it to the `<path>`  it work perfectly fine!

So the loop doesn't work properly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to loop through all the elements with a particular tag name then there's a function that will get all of them: getElementsByTagName.

You were getting the parent `<svg>` element and there's only one of them. You could iterate through its children and find the path elements but why bother given there's an easier way to do it.

```js
const logo= document.getElementsByTagName("path");
for (let i=0; i < logo.length; i++)
{
    console.log(i," ==== ",logo[i].getTotalLength());
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: black;">

        <svg id="logo" width="80" height="90" viewBox="0 0 80 90" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M32.56 3.24001C41.36 3.24001 49.08 4.96001 55.72 8.40001C62.44 11.84 67.6 16.76 71.2 23.16C74.88 29.48 76.72 36.84 76.72 45.24C76.72 53.64 74.88 61 71.2 67.32C67.6 73.56 62.44 78.4 55.72 81.84C49.08 85.28 41.36 87 32.56 87H3.28V3.24001H32.56ZM31.96 72.72C40.76 72.72 47.56 70.32 52.36 65.52C57.16 60.72 59.56 53.96 59.56 45.24C59.56 36.52 57.16 29.72 52.36 24.84C47.56 19.88 40.76 17.4 31.96 17.4H20.08V72.72H31.96Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="6"/>
        </svg>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```